# Evento .on('click', não funciona em input contendo data-md-icheck

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Olá, em minha função tem o evento `.onClick` que deveria ativar ao marcar o `checkbox`, porém quando uso o `data-md-icheck` ele é ignorado pela função.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-md-icheck class="ts_checkbox"/>
```

Evento:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () { 
    $this.click = $(this);
    $this.get();
});
```

Comment: Bom pessoal, acabei encontrando a documentação e a solução. http://icheck.fronteed.com/#callbacks

Comment: Poste como resposta à sua pergunta e, após, marque-a como certa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentação http://icheck.fronteed.com/#callbacks

Usei o comando:

$('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
  alert(event.type + ' callback');
});

Answer (score -1):

For me the event ifChanged works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       var callbacks_list = $('.demo-callbacks ul');
            $('.demo-list input').on('ifCreated ifClicked ifChanged ifChecked ifUnchecked ifDisabled ifEnabled ifDestroyed check', function(event){
                $('#'+this.id+':checkbox').attr('checked', function(idx, oldAttr) {
                   return !oldAttr;
                }); //this manipulates checked state of checkbox
            }).iCheck({
              checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
              radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
              increaseArea: '20%'
            });
          });
```

Comment: Este site é em Português, portanto, é recomendável que sua resposta também seja.